# Background Image Slideshow Clips in FireFox

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

I am using a Background Image slider and it clips in firefox as show below.

FireFox:

[image]

Chrome:
[image]

The Plugin is adding a wierd inline Height in Firefox. Not sure how to override it.

Link: http://play.mink7.com/alankruti-jewellers/

Comment: Have you tried using reset css like normalize?

Comment: Works fine in Firefox for Mac.

Comment: am also on MAC and it doesnt work in Firefox :/

Comment: This link works perfectly in my Firefox browser. I use Windows-7. 
Also works perfectly in Ubuntu too.

Comment: which version of firfox you are using